# Overlay a div but keep elements beneath actionable

Tags: html, css

I have an element with a `<div>` overlaying it to display a grid. I wish to have the grid stay on top of this element, but have everything in the element still actionable and interactive (links, selecting text, etc).

How would I code this?

Comment: with great difficulty. clicks always hit the topmost element in the Z-stack. you'd need to trap them, figure out which "lower" element the click was over, and pass the event on to that element.

Comment: A good question but I thin it was already asked and answered, see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `pointer-events:none;` to the CSS

See this for an example http://jsfiddle.net/Zjq6H/

Comment: Uh oh! Anyone know of Javascript support to polyfill this?